# Knockout JS and iPad update issue on text area / wysiwyg

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

i have an application built with knockout that utilises a wysiwyg called redactor (not that I think that is relevant to this problem but just in case)

I have just run into an issue where a user has an iPad and when they save a 'note' it is missing the last letter each time - nobody else has ever had this issue.

It is evident that this is down to the underlying text area not updating on the last key press, but I am not sure how to fix this.

I have a custom binding as follows

```
ko.bindingHandlers.redactor = {

    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {

        var value = valueAccessor();

        if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
        $(element).redactor({
            changeCallback: value,
            fileUpload: 'url',
            fileManagerJson: site_URL + 'files/files.json',
            plugins: ['filemanager', 'clips', 'textexpander', 'bufferbuttons'],
            textexpander: [
                ["##s", "<strong>(S)</strong> -&nbsp;"]
            ]
        });
    }
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {

        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || '';

        if (value !== $(element).redactor('core.getTextarea').val()) {
            $(element).redactor('code.set', value );
        }
    }
}
```

How can i change this to make sure it behaves as expected on the iPad and updates on the final key press? Or is there a way of simply forcing the update on `keyPress` / `keyDown` within an update.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail about the event flow here? Where are the keys pressed? The code you show updates the on-screen widget when the underlying value changes, but the part of the plumbing that actually changes the underlying value is missing. This is where I would expect that keypress events are handled.

Comment: Hi Tomalak - There is a change callback as part of redactor that updates an underlying textarea, the binding is then against the underlying textarea. I have included the init now as it is actually the important part - I was sleepy when first wrote this question it seems!!

Comment: aha, so the `changeCallback` option of redactor updates the target observable directly. According to [the documentation](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/callbacks/change/), the change callback *"is triggered every time there’s a change in text"*. And on iPad it's not?

Answer (score 1):

The code samples in the documentation retrieve the widget value like this:

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
    callbacks: {
        change: function()
        {
            console.log(this.code.get());
        }
    }   
});
```

In other words, they call `this.code.get()` in the callback body.

Your setup on the other hand...

```
$(element).redactor({
    changeCallback: value
});
```

it implicitly uses the first argument to the callback as the value.

Does it make a difference if you use the same approach the documentation suggests?

```
$(element).redactor({
    changeCallback: function () {
        value(this.code.get());
    });
});
```

Comment: will give that a try and let you know, you get a +1 for a decent and logical suggestion at the very least and hopefully that will work!! cheers

Comment: It might well be that there is something strange going on on iPads. Or maybe some other library is interfering. Hard to say. If it does not work out, make a minimal example on jsFiddle or the like and I try to get hands on an iPad to reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts on this but defo not the solution, thanks though, I have same issue I don't have an iPad with iOS 10 which seems to be issue and don't want to update it yet due to another project....sigh, cheers for the help bud!